# How do we delete subscriber from Auto Suppression List using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Is there a way to delete subscriber from auto suppression list using SSJS?

Any information is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question after doing some more analysis - ET treats Auto Suppression Configurations as Data Extensions. All SSJS functions applicable to DEs works on Auto Suppression Configuration as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use a query activity to also insert/update the data in the Auto-Suppression Configuration? Since it is treated as a Data Extension?