# Add Subscriber to Auto Suppression Lists with SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs, suppressionlist

I am trying to add a Subscriber to an Auto suppression list using SOAP API. 
Here is the envelope I am using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <o:UsernameToken>
            <o:Username>{{soapUsername}}</o:Username>
            <o:Password><![CDATA[{{soapPassword}}]]></o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options>
        </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <CustomerKey>REC5_AG_85</CustomerKey>
            <Properties>
               <Property>
                  <Name>Email Address</Name>
                  <Value>eljazouli@dd.fr</Value>
               </Property>
            </Properties>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But I receive an error `Unable to retrieve Data Extension using CustomerKey`

At the same time, I am using `WSProxy` methods in SSJS to add/remove subscribers to the Auto Supression List witn the same `CustumerKey` and It is working just fine.

Here is the example of SSJS code that deletes a Subscriber

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");


 var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    /* Build DE Object */
    var deleteObject = {
        CustomerKey: 'REC5_AG_85',
        Keys: [
             {
                Name: 'Email Address',
                Value: 'kkk@dd.fr'
            }
        ]
    };


    var res = api.deleteItem('DataExtensionObject', deleteObject);
</script>
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You mention that you are trying to trying to add a record to an [auto suppression list](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_auto_suppresion_lists.htm&type=5) but you are creating a DataExtensionObject (not a SuppressionListDefinition object). Are you sure that you mean an auto suppression list, or do you want to create a record in a DE which will be for suppression?

Comment: @EliotHarper I am refering to the SOAP API documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_auto_suppression_lists_via_the_soap_api.htm and also to the WSProxy where the auto suppression list is populated with DataExtensionObject. Finally I read many posts about Auto Suppression Lists where other people say that they behave like data extensions like here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80034/how-do-we-delete-subscriber-from-auto-suppression-list-using-ssjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SOAP request envelope looks OK to me. The only issue that I can think of is that you have multiple business units on your account. If this is the case, then you will need to define the MID of the BU containing the Auto-suppression list as a Client ID.

Also, I would recommend you consider replacing the legacy Basic Auth username/password with OAuth (which trumps Basic Auth on so many levels).

A sample request is provided below (which I've tested). Replace `12345678` with the MID of the Business Unit where your auto-suppression list exists.

```xml
POST {{soapEndpoint}}
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndpoint}}</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
            <Client>
               <ID>12345678</ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CustomerKey>REC5_AG_85</CustomerKey>
            <Properties>
               <Property>
                  <Name>Email Address</Name>
                  <Value>sam@sample.com</Value>
               </Property>
            </Properties>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks Eliott ! By the way, this feature is not available with field level encryption. I tested in another account and it worked.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks for the additional information.